# How to generate swagger spec from from JAX RS annotated interface?

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I was wondering if there's a way to generate the swagger spec from an existing JAX RS annotated interface, e.g. something like this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface ISampleService {

    @GET
    @Path("sample/foobar/{foobarId}")
    Foobar getFoobar(@PathParam("foobarId") String foobarId);

    @PUT
    @Path("sample/foobar/{foobarId}")
    Foobar updateFoobar(@PathParam("foobarId") String foobarId, Foobar foobar);
}
```

I did find this ["jaxrs analyzer" project](https://github.com/sdaschner/jaxrs-analyzer), but it doesn't seem to recognize my interface.

Basically, I have my service defined in an interface like that, and I want to reverse-engineer the swagger spec to be able to post it so anyone else can generate (other) clients using the swagger functionality.

Preferably, the solution would just work in a maven build (plugin).

Answer (score 11):

Swagger has an easy-to-follow tutorial for Jersey [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5).

In order for Swagger to generate a specification for your resources, you need to add the `@Api` annotation at the top of your class. The available annotations are listed [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X), but I just use `@Api`.

Comment: is there no way to just tell Swagger that "hey, anytime class with `javax.ws.rs.Path` annotations in it, its a swagger doc and make it an api?"